# TypeMismatch in Spring Conversion Service using Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring, type-conversion, model-binding, spring-webflow-2, type-mismatch

We are getting a type mismatch error, while converting our string id to Brand object.  We have searched this forum and followed pretty much all steps, still could not resolve it.  Could u please, take a look at our configuration and our customer conversion service code and help us resolving this error.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="com.latchiya.util.MreachConversionService" />

<bean id="flowMappings" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>

<!-- Executes flows: the entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
                           flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/WEB-INF/flows/**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Plugs in a custom creator for Web Flow views -->
<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" 
         conversion-service="flowConversionService" 
        view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator" /> 



    <bean id="flowConversionService" class="org.springframework.binding.convert.service.DefaultConversionService" >
       <constructor-arg ref="conversionService"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configures Web Flow to use Tiles to create views for rendering; Tiles allows for applying consistent layouts to your views -->
    <bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator"
          class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator"
          p:viewResolvers-ref="viewResolver" />

    <!-- Installs a listener to apply Spring Security authorities -->
    <bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener"
          class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />

<bean name="/socialmediacoupon-flow" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

// Branch Class contains Brand Property

public class Branch extends com.latchiya.model.BaseObject implements java.io.Serializable {
    // Fields
    private Brand brand
  // other fields and getters and setters
}
        //Our Custom Converter

```
@Component
final public class MreachConversionService extends org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean
{
    public MreachConversionService()
    {
        HashSet s = new HashSet();
        s.add(new MreachObjectConverterFactory());
        super.setConverters(s);
    }

    final public class MreachObjectConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String,BaseObject>
    {


        @Override
        public <T extends BaseObject> Converter<String, T> getConverter( Class<T> type )
        {
            return new MreachObjectConverter(type);
        }

        final public class MreachObjectConverter<T> implements Converter<String, T>
        {
            private Manager mgr;
            Class type;
            public void setMgr(Manager mgr)
            {
                this.mgr = mgr;
            }

            /**
            *
            * @param type An instance of Class for the type being converted to
            * @param mgr used to perform the lookup.
            */
            public MreachObjectConverter( Class<T> type)
            {
                this.type = type;
            }

            @Override
            public T convert( String id )
            {
                System.out.println("Brand is : " + type);
                System.out.println("Brand id is : " + id);

                return (T)mgr.getObject(type, java.lang.Long.valueOf(id));



            }
        }

    }
}






<!-- Our JSP  -->

<form:form styleId="branchForm"   commandName="branch">

<form:select path="brand" class="validate[required] select_medium" id="brandId" >
            <form:option value="${null}" label="SELECT"/>
            <form:options items="${brandList}"/>
            </form:select>
<input type="submit" id="next" name="_eventId_save" value="Proceed"></input>
</form:form>
```

//  Our Flow.xml

```
 <view-state id="showBusinessAndLocation"  view="../flows/common/resellerBranchForm" model="branch">
  <transition on="save" to="showCampaignInfo" >
    <evaluate expression="campaignService.saveBranch(branch,userManager.getUserByUsername(currentUser.getName()))" result="flowScope.branch"/>
  </transition>
</view-state>
```

// Our Error

```
2013-09-26 13:47:27,359 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:218)     - Processing user event 'save'
2013-09-26 13:47:27,359 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:223)     - Resolved model com.latchiya.model.Branch@15197119 [branchName='null' addrLine1='null' addrLine2='null' addrLine3='null' city='null' zipcode='null' state='null' country='null' phoneLandline1='null' phoneLandline2='null' phoneFax='null' phoneCell='null' shortCode='null' status='null' emailId='null' contactName='null' createdOn='null' createdBy='null' modifiedOn='null' modifiedBy='null' ]
2013-09-26 13:47:27,359 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:384)     - Binding to model
2013-09-26 13:47:27,375 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:513)     - Adding default mapping for parameter 'shortCode'
2013-09-26 13:47:27,375 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:513)     - Adding default mapping for parameter 'branchId'
2013-09-26 13:47:27,390 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:513)     - Adding default mapping for parameter 'execution'
2013-09-26 13:47:27,390 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:513)     - Adding default mapping for parameter 'brand'
2013-09-26 13:47:27,390 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapper (DefaultMapper.java:60)     - Beginning mapping between source [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalParameterMap] and target [com.latchiya.model.Branch]
2013-09-26 13:47:27,390 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapping (DefaultMappingContext.java:147)     - Adding mapping result [Success@421dc mapping = parameter:'shortCode' -> shortCode, code = 'success', error = false, originalValue = '', mappedValue = '']
2013-09-26 13:47:27,390 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapping (DefaultMappingContext.java:147)     - Adding mapping result [Success@1930aa0 mapping = parameter:'branchId' -> branchId, code = 'success', error = false, originalValue = '', mappedValue = '']
2013-09-26 13:47:27,406 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapping (DefaultMappingContext.java:147)     - Adding mapping result [TargetAccessError@2864cd mapping = parameter:'execution' -> execution, code = 'propertyNotFound', error = true, errorCause = org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found, originalValue = 'e1s1', mappedValue = [null]]
2013-09-26 13:47:27,406 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapping (DefaultMappingContext.java:147)     - Adding mapping result [TargetAccessError@b98ed9 mapping = parameter:'brand' -> brand, code = 'typeMismatch', error = true, errorCause = org.springframework.binding.expression.ValueCoercionException: Value could not be converted to target class; is a suitable type converter registered?, originalValue = '526', mappedValue = [null]]
2013-09-26 13:47:27,406 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] impl.DefaultMapper (DefaultMapper.java:69)     - Completing mapping between source [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalParameterMap] and target [com.latchiya.model.Branch]; total mappings = 4; total errors = 2
2013-09-26 13:47:27,406 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] view.AbstractMvcView (AbstractMvcView.java:230)     - Model binding resulted in errors; adding error messages to context
2013-09-26 13:47:27,421 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] message.DefaultMessageContext (DefaultMessageContext.java:114)     - Resolving message using ***[DefaultMessageResolver@307b0e source = 'brand', severity = ERROR, codes = array<String>['branch.brand.typeMismatch', 'brand.typeMismatch', 'com.latchiya.model.Brand.typeMismatch', 'typeMismatch'], args = array<Object>[[MessageBuilder.ResolvableArgument@df0dac arg = 'brand']], defaultText = 'typeMismatch on brand']
2013-09-26 13:47:27,421 DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-10] message.DefaultMessageContext (DefaultMessageContext.java:119)     - Adding resolved message [Message@1fad846 source = 'brand', severity = ERROR, text = 'typeMismatch on brand']***
```

Comment: i don't sse where exactly you are trying to convert.

Comment: public T convert( String id )
            {
               return (T)mgr.getObject(type, java.lang.Long.valueOf(id));
            } I have put this function in the nested class of MreachObjectConverter inside MreachObjectConverterFactory.